# How to use meshgrid with large arrays in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn

I have trained a machine learning binary classifier on a 100x85 array in sklearn.  I would like to be able to vary 2 of the features in the array, say column 0 and column 1, and generate contour or surface graph, showing how the predicted probability of falling in one category varies across the surface.

It seems reasonable to me that I would use something like the following:

X = 100 x 85 array of data used for training set
clf = Trained 2-class classifier

```
x = np.array(X)
y = np.array(X)

x[:,0] = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y[:,1] = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
xx, yy = meshgrid(x,y)
```

The next step would be to use

`clf.predict_proba(<input arrays>)`

followed by plotting, but using meshgrid results in two 8500x8500 matrices that can't be used in my classifier.

How do I get the necessary 100x85 vector at each point in the grid to use pred_proba with my classifier?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: `np.meshgrid` expects 2 or more 1D input arrays.  You feed it 2x 2D arrays which are being flattened, which is why you get 8500x8500 sized arrays for `xx`, `yy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wflynny says above, you need to give `np.meshgrid` two 1D arrays. We can use `X.shape` to create your `x` and `y` arrays, like this:

```
X=np.zeros((100,85)) # just to get the right shape here

print X.shape
# (100, 85)

x=np.arange(X.shape[0])
y=np.arange(X.shape[1])

print x.shape
# (100,)
print y.shape
# (85,)

xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')

print xx.shape
#(100, 85)
print yy.shape
#(100, 85)
```

Comment: So to build off this question, when I use the classifier to predict a probability, we do clf.predict_proba(xx), which yields a 100x2 matrix.  The second column is the probability of being "True", and I need to plot X[:,0] on the x-axis, and X[:,1] on the y axis.  Trying to do this yields an error...  Any thoughts?

Comment: @tmdavison Thank you so much - you are quite right - the only foolproof way to test this out without going mad is to use a rectangular X rather than a square one! Thank you, thank you